# Broken Edit address link in sales order admin

Tags: admin, magento-1.6, customer-address

I am trying to fix the `Edit Address` links above `Billing and Shipping` addresses in Magento 1.6.1 Admin. They used to work, but stopped some time ago and I'm not sure why.

When you click either of the links, they try to go to the page to edit the chosen address as expected, but nothing loads - just a blank screen, and there is no source code behind it.

Nothing is logged in system or exception logs either!

I have found and followed this info: http://support.createhosting.co.nz/knowledgebase.php?action=displayarticle&id=55

But that didn't change anything on my development site (which is a replica of my live site to test this stuff on first).

How do I go about debugging and fixing this problem?
Cheers!

Comment: Have you looked in the PHP error logs for the site? A blank screen probably means a PHP parsing error.

Comment: Ah thank you, that helped. I have the following error logged there: PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in /home/mydomain/public_html/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Element.php on line 195, referer: http://www.mydomain.co.uk/index.php/admin/sales_order/view/order_id/31174/

Comment: I have checked php.ini in usr/local/lib which is where the ini is loaded from according to php info. I adjusted the max mem to 2048M and restarted Apache. No change. Same error is logged??

Comment: There is also a max memory setting in the sites htaccess file - changing that has resolved the problem! Thanks!

Comment: If you would mark it as an answer, I'll place my comment as an answer and elaborate.

Comment: Enable Magento developer mode or check the Magento system.log or PHP error logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, most often a blank screen indicates a PHP error. Oftentimes, this is indicative of a syntax error, but could also be a memory error (as in your case).

I would recommend looking at the PHP logs to see where the error is. To find them, check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127838/where-does-php-store-the-error-log